# удаление данных из localStorage работает непредсказуемо

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Решительно не понимаю, в чем проблема с удалением требуемых данных из локального хранилища.

Есть таблица прайса. Условно такая:

```
    <table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="user_data"></td><td>Ку-ку</td><td>Ку-ка-ре-ку!</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="user_data"></td><td>2Ку-ку</td><td>Ку-ка-ре-ку!</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name="user_data"></td><td>3Ку-ку</td><td>Ку-ка-ре-ку!</td></tr>
</table><br /><br /><br />
<textarea id="selected" type="text" cols="30" rows="5" style="display:none" /></textarea>   
<table id="rez"></table>
```

Строки из этой таблицы (теги tr) добавляются по клику к форме заказа и сохраняются в localStorage.
Здесь всё работает хорошо. 
Вот код:

```
    //получаем window.a из локального хранилища;
window.a = localStorage.getItem('site_userdata');
if(window.a !== null){document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = window.a;}


$('.checkbox').click(function() {
var tr = $(this).closest("tr").get(0).outerHTML;
var tr = tr.slice(0, -5);
var ntr = '<td><button class="del">X</button></td>';
var end = '</tr>';
var addtr = tr+ntr+end;


if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var currentVal = $('textarea').val();
        $('textarea#selected').val(currentVal + addtr);
        $a = $('textarea#selected').val();
       window.a = $a;
       // сохраняем результат в localStorage:
        localStorage.setItem('site_userdata', window.a);
        $("#rez").append(addtr);}

});
```

То есть, сейчас к форме заказа добавлены строки tr прайса, в которую скриптом дописана ячейка с кнопкой удаления. 
По клику на эту кнопку 1) удаляется родительский тег tr и 2) должно заменяться содержимое локального хранилища.

**И вот с заменой данных в хранилище начинается ПРОБЛЕМА. Этот код работает каждый раз по-разному:**

```
$('#rez').on('click', '.del', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  window.a = $('textarea').val();
  localStorage.setItem('site_userdata', window.a);

});
```

После нажатия на кнопку с классом "del" родительская строка из html удаляется, но из локального хранилища **могут удалиться все строки вместо одной, а может не удалиться ничего**.

То есть **при перезаписи значения localStorage по ключу происходит какая-то ошибка**.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что неправильно и как это исправить.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При перезаписи значения по ключу все происходит правильно. Вы же не обновили значение в `textarea`. Естественно, что там в этот момент находилось, то в `localStorage` и записалось. Сделайте `textarea` видимым на время разработки, чтобы понимать что происходит.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @Наталья Пожалуйста. Успехов!